# Comparing inductances from LCR measurements and FEMM simulations of a simple transformer

Tags: transformer, inductance, coil, wireless-charging, femm

I am trying to compare the results from a simple transformer using two identical Wurth Elektronik inductors (Reference 760308102308, datasheet attached). I measured the inductance with an LCR while doing an open circuit and then a short circuit test. I got 5.6uH for the open circuit and 3.7uH for the short circuit test.

Pictures from the set up are shown below.

[image: LCR Test]

[image: LCR Test Set up]

In addition, I also measure the inductance of these two configurations that I found in another post. The Mutual Inductance found combining the two measurements was 3.77 uH which seems to match the short circuit value and L1 = L2 = 5.22 uH which match with the value found in the previous open-circuit test.

[image: Measuring Mutual Inductance]

I wanted to compare these results from the measurements with a Finite Element Method Magnetics (FEMM42) but when I do the problem and run the simulation the results don't match, and it seems that they are switch. Open Circuit Inductance is 3.7uH and short circuit 6.7uH. I used a current of 1A to simplify the calculations and below you can see the simulation problem and the results I got. I don't know if I am missing something or if I am assuming the wrong conditions or making a mistake in my calculations. I already double-check them and it seems that I cannot connect the LCR Measurements with the results in the simulation

I hope someone can help me understand what I am missing or what I am doing wrong.
All the best, and Thank you for your attention

[image: Simulation]
[image: Open Circuit Primary Results]
[image: Open Circuit Secondary Results]
[image: Short Circuit Primary Results]
[image: Short Circuit Secondary Results]

Comment: Hopefully they’ll be some good discussion here. Another place you can tap into is [the FEMM](https://groups.io/g/femm/) users group.